# break circle into sections for heading

Tags: swift, geometry

I am attempting to break a circle into 3 sections given an angle, this angle determines where the sections will be, for more details on what the sections are search online for aircraft holding patterns.

I'm having trouble getting the logic to work correctly, in the situation where one of the sections spans both sides of 360 degrees. This is what I have so far. both radial and heading are known numbers, in my test case they're 310 and 70 respectively. The code is written in swift.

```
func setEntryLimits(){
    directHigh = abs((radial+110.0).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360))
    directLow = abs((radial-70.0).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360))

    parallelHigh = abs(radial.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360))
    parallelLow = abs((radial+110.0).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360))

    tearDropHigh = abs((radial-70.0).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360))
    tearDropLow = abs(radial.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360))


    turnHeadingDial()

}

func turnHeadingDial(){
    var heading = value*360
    inbound = radial + 180 

    if(tearDropHigh>360||parallelHigh>360||directHigh>360){
    heading = heading+360
    }

    if(tearDropHigh<tearDropLow){
        let tempT = tearDropLow
        tearDropLow = tearDropHigh
        tearDropHigh = tempT
    }

    if(parallelHigh<parallelLow){
        let tempP = parallelLow
        parallelLow = parallelHigh
        parallelHigh = tempP
    }

    if(directHigh<directLow){
        let tempD = directLow;
        directLow = directHigh;
        directHigh = tempD;
    }

    if(inbound>360){
        inbound = inbound-360
    }

    if(heading<tearDropHigh&&heading>(tearDropLow)){
        entryLabel.setText("Tear Drop")
        test1.setText(String(tearDropHigh))
        test2.setText(String(tearDropLow))
    }
    else if(heading<(parallelHigh)&&heading>parallelLow){
        entryLabel.setText("Parallel")
        test1.setText(String(parallelHigh))
        test2.setText(String(parallelLow))
    }
    else if(heading<(directHigh)&&heading>directLow){
        entryLabel.setText("Direct")
        test1.setText(String(directHigh))
        test2.setText(String(directLow))
    }
    else {
        entryLabel.setText("calc error")
    }
    print(tearDropHigh," -tear- ",tearDropLow," ",parallelHigh," -parallel- ",parallelLow," ",directHigh," -direct- ",directLow)

    headingLabel.setText(String(heading))
}
```

Comment: "for more details on what the sections are search online for aircraft holding patterns" Not being mean, but do you really expect fellow users to go and search something for you?

Comment: I mean, explaining or providing a picture would likely increase your chances to get an answer.

Comment: heres a link describing the holding pattern with a few pictures: http://www.touch-n-goes.com/articles/instrument/holdentries.html

setEntryLimits() and turnHeadingDial() are called by the awake function on an Apple Watch app. value is the position of the crown, this will produce a number between 0 and 360 for heading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is vastly more complicated than it needs to be. Simply calculate the difference between the heading and the radial, then normalize that to be between 0 and 360.

Then compare that to the three ranges.

```
let radial = ... // some radial in the range 0-360
let heading = ... // some heading in the range 0-360
let diff = (heading - radial + 360).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360)

if diff >= 110 && diff <= 290 {
    // direct entry
} else if diff > 290 {
    // teardrop entry
} else {
    // parallel entry
}
```

That's all you need.

Comment: Thank you! that solved my issue. I knew there was a way easier way to do it